# Format date in the indexSuccess.php

Tags: date, symfony1, format, symfony-1.4

I want to format the `created_at` field date from the original for something like 03.May.2011 to be shown in the `indexSuccess.php` and in the `showSuccess.php`
Could you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make in symfony in your indexSuccess.php and showSuccess.php instead of for example:

```
 <?php $value->getCreatedAt() ?>
```

next:

```
 <?php echo date('d.M.Y', strtotime($value->getCreatedAt())) ?>
```

You can use [**other**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formats.

Answer (score 3):

The format of some data absolutely not belongs into controller context - so please use

```
use_helper("date");
echo format_date($myDate);
```

from symfony's date helper in your template (showSuccess.php, blaSuccess.php) or partial (form.php, list.php, test.php)  !

You'll find more informations here http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n#chapter_13_sub_outputting_data_in_the_user_s_culture or in the source file.

Comment: thank you so much. so if I have this code:
`<?php echo $sgps_breves->getCreatedAt() ?>` i should write `use_helper("date") echo format_date($sgps_breves->getCreatedAt())`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the date is returned in a string format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, as fits the MySQL datetime type.  It would be nicest to convert this to a PHP `DateTime` instance using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), presuming you are using PHP > 5.3.

So, in your controller:

```
$this->creation_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->created_at);
```

Then, in your view:

```
<?php echo $creation_date->format('d.F.Y') ?>
```

See also [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

---

If you are using PHP 5.2 or before, you can't use `createFromFormat`. You probably want to fall back on [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$this->creation_date = strtotime($this->created_at);
```

and in the view:

```
<?php echo date('d.F.Y', $creation_date) ?>
```

Comment: where do i put the first line of code taht you wrote? i'm kinda new in symfony... still not aware of all the files that symfony creates. thank you by the way:)

Comment: The controller will be `actions.class.php`, in your module's `actions` folder.

Comment: I put the first line in the `executeIndex` function from `action.class.php` and it get me this error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat() in C:\wamp\www\sgps\apps\frontend\modules\breves\actions\actions.class.php on line 18`

Comment: @Eva OK, so you must be using PHP 5.2. In that case, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

To create a datestring like your example (03.May.2011) use this way:

```
<?php use_helper("date"); ?>
<?php echo format_date($myDate,'dd. MMM. yyyy'); ?>
```