# How to set symfony 1.x date format in text box of existing object?

Tags: php, forms, formatting, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony 1.4 form and in it I have a single text box with a datetime string.

I am using jQuery's datetimepicker to simplify date entry instead of having 5 selects.

I already have defaulting the datetime string correct, but I'm not sure how to format the datetime string when I am updating an object.  The string comes back as the default formatting (YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss).

What is the proper way to format existing datetime strings for a symfony textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sfFormExtraPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin). with [sfWidgetFormJQueryDate](http://symfony.com/blog/spice-up-your-forms-with-some-nice-widgets-and-validators) For example:

```
$this->widgetSchema['date_delivery'] = new sfWidgetFormJQueryDate(array(
                'config' => '{}',
                'date_widget' => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%day%/%month%/%year%')),
                'culture' => sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture(),
                'image' => '/images/calendar.png',
                'label' => 'Date'
            ));
```

Or you can use [Unobtrusive Datepicker for symfony - demo](http://garakkio.altervista.org/datepicker/).

If you want formate date in your view you can see [Format date in the indexSuccess.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203559/format-date-in-the-indexsuccess-php/7203787#7203787)